# Search widget breaks when using multiple loops?

Tags: posts, php, wp-query, loop, search

I have created wordpress template that uses two loops via WP_Query object. Everything works fine except **Search widget**. I've been pulling my hairs out for three days now Googling like a madman,but didn't find a solution.
For example in my **searchbox** I type: ***First cat*** (that is the name and content of my post inside "cat" category) and click search and NOTHING happens.

Strange thing is this: if I create a "normal" (main Loop) above other two Loops the **Search widget** WORKS, but the problem is that now my "normal" **(main Loop)** is showing **ALL** posts from my other two loops. 

Can somebody please help me or give a suggestion how to solve this?

[Link to my site](http://robertpeic.com/wordpress_template/) if you want to check my non working search widget:(
**Index.php** look's like this:

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar('Main Sidebar'); ?>   
<div id="blogwrapper">  
<div id="blog">  
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>        
    <?php                             
    $paged1 = isset( $_GET['paged1'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged1'] : 1;
    $paged2 = isset( $_GET['paged2'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged2'] : 1;
    $args=array(

    'category_name' => 'cats',
    'paged' => $paged1,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order' => 'DESC'
     );
     $temp = $wp_query;
     $wp_query= null;
     $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
     while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
     ?>     
    <div class="post">  
    <div class="post_title">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </div>
        <div class="entry"> 

        <!--< ?php the_meta(); ?>-->

            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content('Read on...'); ?>

            <p class="postmetadata">
            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <br/><?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="navigation">
    <?php
     $pag_args1 = array(
        'format'  => '?paged1=%#%',
        'current' => $paged1,       
        'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,      
        'add_args' => array( 'paged2' => $paged2 )
    );
    echo paginate_links( $pag_args1 );
    ?>
    </div>      
    <?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
    </div><!--/blog-->          
    <div id="blogs">    
    <?php            
$args2=array(

'category_name' => 'dogs',
'paged' => $paged2,
'posts_per_page' => 2
);
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args2);
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="post">      
    <div class="post_title">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </div>
        <div class="entry"> 
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content('Read on...'); ?>
            <p class="postmetadata">
            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>       
    <div class="navigation">        
    <?php
       $pag_args2 = array(
        'format'  => '?paged2=%#%',
        'current' => $paged2,
        'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'add_args' => array( 'paged1' => $paged1 )
    );
    echo paginate_links( $pag_args2 );
    ?>
    </div>      
    <?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>              
    </div>
     </div><!--blogswrapper-->
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Modified **Index.php** with Main loop that kinda works (Main loop showing all the post's from other two loops,but search widget WORKS..)

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar('Main Sidebar'); ?>   
<div id="blogwrapper"> 
    <div id="blog">
       //Now Search Widget is WORKING but its's showing posts from 
       //other TWO LOOPS so it looks like a BIG mess:( 
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <div class="entry"> 
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <p class="postmetadata">
            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="navigation">
    <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>  
<div id="blog">  
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>        
    <?php                             
    $paged1 = isset( $_GET['paged1'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged1'] : 1;
    $paged2 = isset( $_GET['paged2'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged2'] : 1;
    $args=array(

    'category_name' => 'cats',
    'paged' => $paged1,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order' => 'DESC'
     );
     $temp = $wp_query;
     $wp_query= null;
     $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
     while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
     ?>     
    <div class="post">  
    <div class="post_title">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </div>
        <div class="entry"> 

        <!--< ?php the_meta(); ?>-->

            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content('Read on...'); ?>

            <p class="postmetadata">
            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <br/><?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="navigation">
    <?php
     $pag_args1 = array(
        'format'  => '?paged1=%#%',
        'current' => $paged1,       
        'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,      
        'add_args' => array( 'paged2' => $paged2 )
    );
    echo paginate_links( $pag_args1 );
    ?>
    </div>      
    <?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
    </div><!--/blog-->          
    <div id="blogs">    
    <?php            
$args2=array(

'category_name' => 'dogs',
'paged' => $paged2,
'posts_per_page' => 2
);
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args2);
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="post">      
    <div class="post_title">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </div>
        <div class="entry"> 
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content('Read on...'); ?>
            <p class="postmetadata">
            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>       
    <div class="navigation">        
    <?php
       $pag_args2 = array(
        'format'  => '?paged2=%#%',
        'current' => $paged2,
        'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'add_args' => array( 'paged1' => $paged1 )
    );
    echo paginate_links( $pag_args2 );
    ?>
    </div>      
    <?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>              
    </div>
     </div><!--blogswrapper-->
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you read: [*When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/12615)

Comment: Thx for the tip but I an not great with PHP, but I DID tried to solve my problem using WP_Query and even query_posts()...but as I was saying not that good with PHP. If you have suggestions for solving this that would be great... THX again

Comment: Loops and pagination are not my area. Just wanted to make sure `query_posts` was not the culprit.

Comment: Deleted my question from Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody shoot me please... Since this is the first theme I developed I didn't know that I needed a **search.php** for my form to work! Anyway I created search.php and inserted The Loop, after I did that I've copied that file inside my theme and my search form worked like a charm!! 
Hope this will help somebody else :) 
**My search.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying Search Results pages.
*
* 
* 
* 
*/
    get_header(); ?>
<div id="blog">
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <div class="entry"> 
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <p class="postmetadata">
            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="navigation">
    <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```